# Excel help to remove part of a field

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have multiple locations that have a distance marker that I need removed.  They differ in distance and some just don't have it.

Here's an example:  (0m) KISD CTB

Comment: Please read ***[ask]***, then update your question with some details. As is, it is difficult to know what you need, or have tried. There is a good chance this question will be closed unless you improve it.

Comment: Is the distance always of the format `(#m) `? If that's the case, the logic is: 1) Check if the left character is "(", 2) Find the first ")", 3) Remove everything before that and trim off any spaces. Try looking up how to do those steps and come back with questions.

Answer (score 1):

With data in **A1**, in **B1** enter:

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND(")",A1,1)),A1,MID(A1,FIND(")",A1,1)+2,9999))
```

and copy down:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Gary's Student has what is probably an OK answer although this option is more robust:

```
=IF(LEFT(TRIM(A1),1)<>"(",A1,TRIM(MID(A1,IFERROR(FIND(")",A1)+1,1),LEN(A1))))
```

You get the idea, though.